# Spring Cloud - Cannot Register Service with eureka server locally

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to configure the Eureka port with Spring Cloud with a eureka server, and config server (which is also a eureka client). Eureka service is successfully deployed and got a ip address. My Goal is to get the instance under eureka server.

I'm getting below error

2022-05-24 12:26:10.914 ERROR 21280 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

2022-05-24 12:03:09.673  WARN 21280 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

This is my application.yml file from the test-service

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[ip address]/[address]
    username: *******
    password: *******
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  profiles:
    active:@activatedProperties@
  jpa:
     database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
     hibernate:
       use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
       ddl-auto: update
  application:
    name: test-service
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: 'true'
  client:
    fetchRegistry: 'true'
    registerWithEureka: 'true'
    enabled: 'true'
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://[username]:[password]@localhost:8761/eureka
   
server:
  port: 8080
  
Debug: true
```

This is my eureka-serviece application.property file

```
server.port=8761
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation = false

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF

spring.security.user.name=******
spring.security.user.password=*******
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
```